# Show that the Absolute Value Function Is not Rational

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

I was asked to prove that the absolute value function over $\mathbb R^2$ is not rational.  Then, I realized that I never proved the single-variable case in the past.  Suppose that $|x|$ is rational, and write:
$$|x| \sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i = \sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k$$

Set $x = 0$ to obtain $c_0 = 0$.  Then, rewrite the above into:

$$|x| \sum_{i=0}^m a_ix^i = \sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k = \sum_{k=1}^n c_kx^k$$
$$a_0|x| + |x|x \sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^{i-1} = x \sum_{k=1}^n c_kx^{k-1}$$

Suppose that $a_0 = 0$.  Then, if we divide both sides by $x$, we have $|x| \sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^{i-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_kx^{k-1}$.

I want to argue that $a_0$ cannot be zero, entailing that $Q(0) \ne 0$.  Hence, $|x| = P(x)/Q(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, which is not true.  What exactly am I violating in the expression below, minimal degree in $Q(x), P(x)$ because of well-ordering, irreducibility, or ...?

$$|x| \sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^{i-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_kx^{k-1}$$

Plus, if it is not too much trouble, can you explain the difference between irreducibility and prime?  I was trying to learn the material on my own, but this time I really am lost with just the definitions and no problems for motivation.

Comment: Umm...what's the absolute value function over $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Perhaps it is the $L^1$-norm??

Comment: I think the *differentiability* of rational functions at any point where continuous is a good starting point.  I wouldn't get too distracted by irreducible vs. prime (they are the same in a UFD, and univariate polynomials over a field are even nicer than that).

Comment: I think the *intended* question is to show that the function $|x|$ is not a rational function of $x$ (with real coefficients, presumably). And then the original question inspiring this must have been to show the norm on $\mathbf R^2$, namely $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, is not a rational function in $x$ and $y$ (with real coefficients). The question should really be rewritten to avoid being opaque.

Comment: I'd just go with the simple contradiction approach:  Rational functions are differentiable wherever they are defined,  $|x|$ isn't

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove that the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$ is not a rational function, your starting point was good: you write $$\lvert x\rvert \sum a_i x^i=\sum b_i x^i.$$
Then, you observe that every positive real number is a zero of the polynomial 
$x \sum a_i x^i-\sum b_i x^i$, so this one should be zero (a non-zero polynomial has only finitely many roots).  This implies that $ x\sum a_i x^i=\sum b_i x^i,$ for any real number $x\in \mathbb{R}$, which contradicts the above inequality for $x$ negative.